# javascript function document.location working incorrectly

Tags: javascript, document, location

When I change on proxy-server page from cnn.com (I add javascript, that call document.location), result of the document.location is some url of advertisement: http://ads.cnn.com/html.ng/site=cnn_international&cnn_intl_pagetype=mmst&cnn_intl_position=336x850_rgt&cnn_intl_rollup=asia&page.allowcompete=yes&params.styles=fs&tile=5656033441721&domId=894131

and not current url:http://edition.cnn.com/2010/WORLD/asiapcf/04/13/soccer.world.cup.pakistan/index.html?hpt=C1

Do you know, where can be problem?
edit:Problem is the same with using window.location.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code, its hard to say where the problem is.  There's a good chance the proxy server process may be interfering with things, can you verify what your code does without using the proxy server?